# ARSV model estimation with (constrained) generalized method of moments in R

Tags: r, estimation, optimization, generalized-moments, volatility

I am trying to perform the estimation of the following Autoregressive Stochastic Volatility model
$$
y_t=\sigma_t u_t = exp(w_t/2)u_t \\
w_t = \omega + \phi w_{t-1} + \eta_t
$$
in R via the function `gmm` of the homonymous package.

The following lines of code contain the function, with the 12 moment conditions that I am using, and the estimation command

```
  target_f = function(theta, x){
  omega = theta[1]
  phi = theta[2]
  sigma2_eta = theta[3]
  data = x
  alpha_w = omega / (1 - phi)
  beta2_w = sigma2_eta / (1 - phi^2)
  
  m1 = (sqrt(2/pi) * exp(0.5 * alpha_w + 0.125 * beta2_w) - abs(data))[-(1:10)]
  m2 = (exp(alpha_w + 0.5*beta2_w) - data ^ 2)[-(1:10)]
  m3 = (2 * sqrt(2/pi)*exp(3/2*alpha_w + 9/8 * beta2_w) - abs(data^3))[-(1:10)]
  m4 = (3 * exp(2 * alpha_w + 2 * beta2_w) - data^4)[-(1:10)]
  
  m5 = ((2/pi) * exp(0.5 * alpha_w + 0.125 * beta2_w)^2 * (phi*beta2_w/4) - abs(data * lag(data)))[-(1:10)]
  m6 = ((2/pi) * exp(0.5 * alpha_w + 0.125 * beta2_w)^2 * exp(phi^2 * beta2_w/4) - abs(data * lag(data, 2)))[-(1:10)]
  m7 = ((2/pi) * exp(0.5 * alpha_w + 0.125 * beta2_w)^2 * exp(phi^5 * beta2_w/4) - abs(data * lag(data, 5)))[-(1:10)]
  m8 = ((2/pi) * exp(0.5 * alpha_w + 0.125 * beta2_w)^2 * exp(phi^10 * beta2_w/4) - abs(data * lag(data, 10)))[-(1:10)]
  
  m9 = (exp(alpha_w + 0.5*beta2_w)^2 * exp(phi * beta2_w) - data^2 * lag(data)^2)[-(1:10)]
  m10 = (exp(alpha_w + 0.5*beta2_w)^2 * exp(phi^2 * beta2_w) - data^2 * lag(data, 2)^2)[-(1:10)]
  m11 = (exp(alpha_w + 0.5*beta2_w)^2 * exp(phi^5 * beta2_w) - data^2 * lag(data, 5)^2)[-(1:10)]
  m12 = (exp(alpha_w + 0.5*beta2_w)^2 * exp(phi^10 * beta2_w) - data^2 * lag(data, 10)^2)[-(1:10)]
  return(
    cbind(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9, m10, m11, m12)
  )
}

# Estimation
ret = rnorm(1000)
ARSV_fit =
  gmm(g = target_f, x = ret, t0 = c(0, 0, 1), wmatrix = "optimal")
```

.

Unfortunately, the optimization is very reliable on the starting point that I provide, and in this way, it happens that it returns negative values for the variance parameter.
Is there any way to insert constraint on the parameters within `gmm` or do you know any other function that allows so?